# Rotate and summarize a part of a SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pivot, case

Hey there I'm new to SQL. I have a table like this and I want to transform/write it to another table.

```
|sessionid |key  |value|
-----------------------
|12345678  |key1 |val1 |
|12345678  |key1 |val2 |
|12345678  |key1 |val3 |
|12345678  |key1 |val4 |
|12345678  |key1 |val5 |
|12345678  |key2 |lav1 |
|12345678  |key2 |lav2 |
|12345678  |key2 |lav3 |
|12345678  |key2 |lav4 |
|12345678  |key3 |lav1 |
|12345678  |key3 |lav2 |
```

and I want to write to a new table with this format:

```
|sessionid |key1 |key2 |
------------------------
|12345678  |val1 |lav1 |
|12345678  |val2 |lav2 |
|12345678  |val3 |lav3 |
|12345678  |val4 |lav4 |
|12345678  |val5 |null |
```

What I have is this:

```
SELECT sessionid ,
        
    -- KEY1        
        CASE 
            WHEN logtagname = 'key1' 
            THEN value 
        END AS 'vp_session_id',
        
    -- KEY2        
        CASE 
            WHEN logtagname = 'key2' 
            THEN value 
        END AS 'diy_module',

FROM    table
```

which returns this:

```
|sessionid|key1 |key2 |
-----------------------
|12345678 |val1 |null |
|12345678 |val2 |null |
|12345678 |val3 |null |
|12345678 |val4 |null |
|12345678 |val5 |null |
|12345678 |null |lav1 |
|12345678 |null |lav2 |
|12345678 |null |lav3 |
|12345678 |null |lav4 |
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: What if there are more than 2 keys?

Comment: @forpas then the should be ignored I'll edit my question thank you

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you can get the values in separate columns using conditional aggregation (with a twist).  But you cannot control which key values line up.  For that you need to have an ordering column.

The idea is:

```
select sessionid,
       max(case when key = 'key1' then value end) key1,
       max(case when key = 'key2' then value end) key2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sessionid, key order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by sessionid, seqnum;
```

Comment: syntax error to use near '(PARTITION BY sessionid...

Comment: @Soteri . . . This syntax has been available in MySQL since version 8.0 was released about 2.5 years ago.